# Array of custom type initialization between braces

Tags: c++, arrays

i'm struggling and trying to understand why the following code is not working.

I have 3 classes defined as:

```
class VertexType
{
public:
    VertexType(void) { };
    virtual ~VertexType() = 0;
};

class PositionColorVertex
    : public VertexType
{
public:
    PositionColorVertex(XMFLOAT3 _position, XMFLOAT4 _color)
    :Position(_position), Color(_color)
    {};
    ~PositionColorVertex() {};

    static const UINT size = 28;

    XMFLOAT3 Position;
    XMFLOAT4 Color;
};

class PositionVertex
    : public VertexType
{
public:
    PositionVertex(XMFLOAT3 _position)
    :Position(_position)
    {};
    ~PositionVertex() {};

    static const UINT size = 12;

    XMFLOAT3 Position;
};
```

The array initialization is working for:

```
PositionVertex vertices[] = { XMFLOAT3(0,0,0) };
```

but when i try to initialize with:

```
PositionColorVertex vertices[] = {
{ XMFLOAT3(0,0,0), XMFLOAT4(0,0,0,1) } };
```

i get an error C2552 non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list.

Why PositionVertex is working whereas PositionColorVertex isn't ?

Comment: the name is wrong *PositionVertexColor* while the class is called *PositionColorVertex*.. hope it's only a copy & paste error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why PositionVertex is working whereas PositionColorVertex isn't ?

Because in the first case you are initializing an array, which is an aggregate:

```
PositionVertex vertices[] = { XMFLOAT3(0,0,0) };
```

In the second case, you are attempting to initialize a `PositionVertexColor` with an initializer list containing two elements, *then* use that to initialize a size-1 array. The first part only works in C++11. You can visualize it better by splitting this:

```
PositionVertexColor vertices[] = { {XMFLOAT3(0,0,0), XMFLOAT4(0,0,0,1)} };
```

into two:

```
PositionVertexColor pvc =  {XMFLOAT3(0,0,0), XMFLOAT4(0,0,0,1)}; // Error, non-aggregate.
PositionVertexColor vertices[] = { pvc }; // would be OK if first step had worked
```

Comment: OK. So the only way to have the array initialisation work is to use `PositionColorVertex vertices[] = { PositionColorVertex(XMFLOAT3(0,0,0), XMFLOAT4(0,0,0,1)), PositionColorVertex(XMFLOAT3(0,0,0), XMFLOAT4(0,0,0,1)) };`

Comment: @LoulG. Yes, or use a compiler with C++11 support, in which case what you tried originally should work.